# How to create a button , which after being clicked to go back to an Activity where were already put values in sharedPref and to edit those values?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How to create a button , which after being clicked to go back to an Activity where were already put values in sharedPref and to edit those values?
Im trying to make an app where a User enters his Height,Weight,Age and chooses from a radioGroup radioButtons - Male or Female and after clicking the "Next" button it goes to a Main Menu where it displays those values which the user just input. I've made a if where it looks if the values are already entered before and if they are , it just skips the Activity and it goes directly to the Main Menu. I want to make a button Edit where , when it gets clicked to go back to the Activity where user can edit the values which he input before. I'm posting the code of My MainActivity and My MainMenu below , will appreciate the answers
P.S. I'm new to coding and I'm not understanding everything , that's why I'm asking a question , would love to see a simple detailed explanation of the steps to do the thing i want in the codes. Thank you guys!
MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText enterHeight, enterWeight, enterAge;

private double height;
private double weight;
private double age;
String selectedRadiobut;
Button button;
RadioButton radioMale, radioFemale;
RadioGroup radioGroup;
SharedPreferences sp;

private boolean heightIsValid() {

    if (enterHeight.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
        enterHeight.setError("Cant be empty");
        return false;
    }

    double height = Double.valueOf(enterHeight.getText().toString());

    if (height <= 0) {

        enterHeight.setError("Cant be zero");
        return false;
    }
    if (height <= 40 || height > 250) {

        enterHeight.setError("Cant be less than 40 cm or more than 250 cm");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean weightIsValid() {
    if (enterWeight.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
        enterWeight.setError("Cant be empty");
        return false;
    }

    double weight = Double.valueOf(enterWeight.getText().toString());

    if (weight <= 0) {

        enterWeight.setError("Cant be zero");
        return false;
    }
    if (weight > 600) {

        enterWeight.setError("Cant be more than 600 kg");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean ageIsValid() {
    if (enterAge.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
        enterAge.setError("Cant be empty");
        return false;
    }

    double age = Double.valueOf(enterAge.getText().toString());

    if (age <= 0) {

        enterAge.setError("Cant be zero");
        return false;
    }
    if (age > 116) {

        enterAge.setError("Cant be older than 116 years");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean genderIsSelected() {

    if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) { //checking if the user has selected a option using id
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Please select gender", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        return false;
    }
    if (radioMale.isChecked()) {
        selectedRadiobut = radioMale.getText().toString();
    } else if (radioFemale.isChecked()) {
        selectedRadiobut = radioFemale.getText().toString();
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
    sp = getSharedPreferences("MyUserPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (sp.contains("height") && sp.contains("weight") && sp.contains("age") && sp.contains("gender")) {
        // Values are stored, navigate to MainMenu directly
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainMenu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        radioMale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioMale);
        radioFemale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioFemale);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        enterHeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterHeight);
        enterWeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterWeight);
        enterAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterAge);
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                if (heightIsValid() & weightIsValid() & ageIsValid() & genderIsSelected()) {

                    height = Double.valueOf(enterHeight.getText().toString());
                    weight = Double.valueOf(enterWeight.getText().toString());
                    age = Double.valueOf(enterAge.getText().toString());

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                    editor.putString("height", String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf((int) height)));
                    editor.putString("weight", String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf((int) weight)));
                    editor.putString("age", String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf((int) age)));
                    editor.putString("gender", String.valueOf(selectedRadiobut));
                    editor.commit();

                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainMenu.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MainMenu:

public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

Button  btnMC , btnFN , btnRec , btnGuides, btnEdit;

```
public void btnStepClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, StepCounter.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void btnCalClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MacrosCalculator.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void btnRecClick(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Recipes.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void btnEditClick(View view){
    Log.d("MainMenu", "Edit button clicked");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
    TextView age1 , height1 , weight1 , gender1;

    age1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.age1);
    height1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.height1);
    weight1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weight1);
    gender1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gender1);
    btnMC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMC);
    btnFN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFN);
    btnRec = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRec);
    btnGuides = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGuides);
    btnEdit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);

    SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyUserPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String height = sp.getString("height" , "");
    String weight = sp.getString("weight" , "");
    String age = sp.getString("age" , "");
    String gender= sp.getString("gender", "");

    gender1.setText("Gender: " + gender);
    age1.setText("Age: " + age);
    height1.setText("Height(cm): " + height);
    weight1.setText("Weight(kg): " + weight);


}
```

}

I wanted to create a button EDIT , and when it gets clicked to go back to the MainActivity , but when it gets clicked , the app crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! I had to make the values from the sharedprefs to be removed after clicking the button. So in buttonClick I had to put the sharedpref and then the sp.edit().remove("Value").commit(). My values in the example are 4 so I put 4 of them as I have shown below :).

```
public void btnEditClick(View view){
        Log.d("MainMenu", "Edit button clicked");
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("MyUserPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        sp.edit().remove("height").commit();
        sp.edit().remove("weight").commit();
        sp.edit().remove("age").commit();
        sp.edit().remove("gender").commit();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).